# Dual monitor wallpaper don't appear correctly after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04, desktop-background

After upgrading to 22.04, the dual-screen wallpaper does not appear correctly on a dual monitor system. Only part of the wallpaper is repeatedly shown on both monitors instead of showing the entire wallpaper on both monitors. How do I fix this issue?

**Settings --> Display**

[image: Display Settings]

**Dual monitor (2x 1920x1080) appearance:**

[image: Dual monitors]

**Wallpaper (2560x1024):**

[image: Wallpaper]

Comment: Have you attempted to reset your wallpaper? Are your screen resolutions correct? Is it only the wallpaper not working, or do you have other display issues?

Comment: @DankyNanky Yes. Yes. Only wallpaper don't appear correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The `Background` `Adjustment` defaults to `Zoom`. It needs to be set to `Spanned`. I used the `Tweaks` application to do this.

**Solution via Tweaks:**

[image: solution1]

Dual monitor (2x 1920x1080) appearance:

[image: Dual Monitor2]

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't answer your question, but for others looking for a wallpaper updater that handles multiple screens, you can check out my github.

I've created a bash script and autostart file for single or dual screen wallpapers. This assumes you want to randomly display different images on each monitor, from a directory containing the wallpaper images you want to sequence through.

https://github.com/kendalla59/wallup/releases/tag/v1.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1327302)